# Is it correct to write "two possible approaches on how to solve this issue will be discussed - public awareness campaigns and public services"?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, em-dashes

I am especially interested if the hyphen in the sentence is used correctly and if this can be called a hyphen in the first place. This [source](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html#) states that it should rather be called "em-dash".

Comment: This does not address the issue of the punctuation so it's a comment rather than an answer but it would be better to say "...approaches to..." rather than "...approaches on...". Originally an approach was (and still is) a physical movement made towards a place or person, later it became a means of approach such as a path, a drive or a paved area and has come to mean a conceptual method of problem solving more recently still. However the approach is still made _to_ the goal, not _on_ it.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions already on this site: look at the tags [em-dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/em-dash) and [dashes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dashes).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look at this website https://www.howtogeek.com/812094/whats-the-difference-between-em-dash-en-dash-and-hyphen/. According to it, hyphen is smallest, en-dash is in-between, em-dash is biggest.

To know whether it is hyphen, en-dash or em-dash go to https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer .

An em-dash is often used to separate interjections or parenthetical phrases, without interrupting the flow of the sentence. So your sentence is better served with an em-dash. And if used, it should be used like this example sentence (in https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/em-dash-en-dash-how-to-use)

> Mabel the Cat was delighted with the assortment of pastries the new
> bakery featured, but Harry the Dog—he felt otherwise.

P.S. If the answer is useful kindly upvote, if the answer is not useful kindly downvote. Click the tick on the answer or answers amongst all the answers—that completely answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Two possible approaches on how to solve this issue will be discussed: public awareness campaigns and public services.

Use a colon to introduce a list.

Comment: [Or you can use a comma or a dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/comma-and-dash-introducing-a-list)